# Python weakref on function return values

Tags: python, weak-references

Is it possible to create weakref from function return values, if so how?

1. Do you return weakref.proxy from the function itself: return weakref.proxy(returnval)
2. Or wrap the return val in weakref.proxy when calling the func weakref.proxy(func)

   ```
   import pandas
   import weakref

   mkt_df = weakref.proxy(pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='filepath', delimiter=','))
   print(mkt_df)
   ```

I can't get either them to work as I get a reference error while proxy
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly possible, but it's also useless. Unless the function is storing a strong reference somewhere else (an internal cache or the like), when you wrap the call in `weakref.ref`/`weakref.proxy`, the following occurs:

1. Function returns a strong reference (only one strong reference exists, with the owner being the caller)
2. Strong reference is passed to `ref`/`proxy` constructor (transferring strong ref ownership to the weak reference constructor as a local variable), creating a weak reference
3. As soon as the constructor returns, it releases the strong reference to the argument it was passed
4. Since no other strong references exist, the return value is immediately freed, and the weak reference is cleared

Simply put, weak references are only useful if you have some expectation that a strong reference will stick around for a while somewhere else; in this case, you've *guaranteed* it won't in normal cases, so the weak reference is useless.

If you want a weak reference that's useful, you'd need to store a strong reference somewhere, then create a weak reference from it, e.g.:

```
mkt_df_strong = pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='filepath', delimiter=',')
mkt_df_weak = weakref.proxy(mkt_df_strong)
# The weak reference now remains useful until the strong reference disappears
```